# React Router - Should I render all the routes at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Suppose I have an application, where you can login both as user or admin and I have this routes:

- Log In
- Register
- Home
- Admin panel (only available to admins)
- My Profile (only available to users)

I would have a switch with routes like this:

```
<Switch>
    <UnloggedRoute exact path='/login'>
        <Login />
    </Route>
    <UnloggedRoute exact path='/register'>
        <Register />
    </Route>
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/'>
        <HomePage />
    </Route>
    <AdminRoute exact path='/admin'>
        <Admin />
    </Route>
    <UserRoute exact path='/profile'>
        <Profile />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

So inside `PrivateRoute` I have a conditional that checks if the user is logged in, if not, it redirects to `/login`. In `AdminRoute` it checks if the user is admin, if not, redirects to `/` and in `UserRoute` I have a conditional that checks if the user is a normal user, if not, redirects to `/`.

Finally, in the `UnloggedRoute` I have a check to see if the user is logged in. If it is, then it goes to `/`.

So my question is: should I leave the switch like it is, or should I not render the route "Profile" if the user is an admin? Like this:

```
user.isAdmin() && (
    <Route exact path='/admin'>
        <Admin />
    </Route>
)
```

I feel like the first way is more declarative and easier to understand and manage, but I want to hear opinions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for my app, I did something pretty similar to how you did it in the first way. I had to deal with 4 different logins using 5 different routes being: `MainRoute`, `TeacherRoute`, `StudentRoute`, `TutorRoute`, and `AdminRoute`. For my uses, I simply had each one of these routes check the `accountType` (or `isAdmin()` in your case) within the route itself like so:

```
const PrivateRouteAdmin = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  //If login is good, allow access or redirect to login
  if (!!currentUser) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={routeProps =>
          (currentUser.isAdmin()) ? (
            <RouteComponent {...routeProps}
              currentUser={currentUser} />
          ) : (
              <Redirect to={"/incorrect-login"} />
            )
        }
      />
    )
  } else {
    //Bad login
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={() => (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default PrivateRoutedAdmin;
```

As long as you check the routes like so within the routes, you don't need to do the `isAdmin()` within the `Switch`.

Also, to keep things a bit more organized within your `Switch`, I would do:

```
<AdminRoute exact path='/admin' component={Admin} />
```